# How to set RStudio R console working directory from r-markdown chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am attempting to make a workflow as foolproof as possible using rmds and Git. Here, new rmd files and updates to old files are served via Git which is used by RStudio shell.

The issue is with different working directories between individual rmd files and the R console in RStudio. By default, the shell from which Git is used opens to the working directory of the R console. However, by default, rmd files work in the folder they are residing in, which is necessarily not the same as the R console working directory.

I am aware of the solution that sets the working directory of all cells within one rmd file (below), but this will not change the working directory of the R console, only chunks.

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "path/to/desired/wd")
```

Hence, I'd ask if anyone is aware of a way of forcing the R console working directory to match the rmd working directory. Ideally, this would be done within an rmd cell in a way that executing one cell would take care of matching the working directories automatically.

Comment: Making a workflow foolproof entails *not touching the working directory!* And RMarkdown enforces this by resetting any changes to the working directory. It also runs in an isolated session that’s distinct from the R console. The only foolproof way is therefore to **not rely on the current working directory in your code**.

Comment: I found useful to use RStudio projects combined with `here` package. When the `Rmd` is inside a project, you can reference data inside the project relative to the root folder of the project using `here::here()`, see [Ode to the here package](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here).

Comment: Thanks for your comments; I might have written my question poorly. Regarding data, I do use the rmd isolated session working directory and relative paths to data files. My trouble is in when an rmd file is open in RStudio, and the user opens the shell, the shell is in a different directory than the rmd. Then, if the user opens the rmd, they might think that the shell is in the same directory, and do a git pull without thinking. If the shell is not, however, in the same directory as the rmd, the pull will fail.

This might be splitting hairs already but it would be interesting to know.